# Meta viewport rendering into the body

Tags: xhtml, meta-tags

I'm having trouble with [a mobile website](http://m.niten.org.br/cafe-com-sensei), where I don't have direct access to the source (my task was changing CSS only).

I requested the developer to insert the viewport meta tag at the header

but Chrome Inspector shows it as a wrapper to everything below, creating a weird closing tag at the end of the body.

What might be causing this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QryBj.png

Comment: Is viewport meta tag closed with `/>` ? check in plain html source

Answer (score 0):

The spaces in the viewport meta tag are non-breaking spaces, so the tag is not being recognised correctly. Get the developer to fix the spaces in the tag.